# Where does grails store a self-generated SSL certificate?

Tags: grails, ssl

I'm running grails on my local dev box (Mac OS 10.8) to host a web service over SSL using a self-signed certificate and the WeakSSL grails plugin. The problem is I'm connecting to this server through an Xcode iPhone simulator, and it's giving me an untrusted certificate error.

I've found instructions on how to install a certificate to the phone/simulator, but my question is how do I find this certificate on my machine to install?

Comment: Do you have an `ssl` directory inside the grails project working directory? (`../workDir/ssl`)

Comment: @dmahapatro No, nor can I find anything in ~/.grails or /usr/share/grails.

Comment: Did you look into `.grails/2.2.1` or which ever version of grails you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you are using grails 2.2.x you won't see the directory in `~.grails/`. To find the keystore, the plugin uses a `Pattern` matched to Grails version `1.3.x` and `2.0.x - 2.1.x`.

Ideally you should see the certificates stored in `~./grails/${grailsVersion}`

Have a look a the [plugin code where certificates are found](https://github.com/hartsock/WeakSSL/blob/master/src/java/com/blogspot/hartsock/ssl/weak/GrailsAutoTrustModeSSL.java).

[Created JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10117) defect for the same.

Pattern matcher will not work for Grails version 2.2.x and above because of the below code.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

Pattern V2X = Pattern.compile("2.[01].\\d+?")
assert  !V2X.matcher("2.2.0").find()
```

Comment: Super thanks, I found it in `~/.grails/2.1.0/projects/api/ssl` based on the code you linked to. (Note to others, "api" is the app name.)

Answer (score 0):

Also, consider using openssl to get the key directly from the running grails server with a command like this:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443
```

AFTER starting grails with something like this:

```
grails run-app -https
```

The output of the openssl command will have the self signed certificate that you can add to your clients trusted certificates.

Comment: Sometimes this doesn't work.  I've been doing it for a year now and today... I tried to move my dev env from Mac OS to Linux and this didn't work with Grails on Linux.